# Função javascript para divisão retornando NaN

Tags: javascript, divisão

Faaaala pessoal, to com uma dúvida...

Por que quando eu passo dois valores por parâmetro nessa função de divisão está retornando NaN? Se eu agregar valores as variaveis antes tudo bem. Porém quando passo na chamada da função o problema aparece.

```
var divicao = function (valor1, valor2){
    var resultado = valor1 / valor2;
    return resultado;
}
```

Exemplo onde retornaria NaN:

```
 console.log(divicao(1/2));
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar na pergunta um exemplo de uso que retorna um `NaN`?

Comment: Sim irei adicionar, perdão

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está chamando a função errado, tem que separar os parâmetros por vírgula:

```js
var divicao = function (valor1, valor2){
    var resultado = valor1 / valor2;
    return resultado;
}

//so coloquei para um alert para ficar mais fácil de ver o retorno
alert(divicao(1,2))

// no console
console.log(divicao(1,2))
```

Melhorando um pouco seu código:

```js
//Você pode retornar direto o valor da divisão
var divicao = function (valor1, valor2){
    return valor1 / valor2;
 }

//so coloquei para um alert para ficar mais fácil de ver o retorno
alert(divicao(1,2))

// no console
console.log(divicao(1,2))
```

Comment: Só para completar, `divisao(1/2)` é equivalente a  `divisao(0.5, undefined)`

Comment: Pessoal obrigado, acabei não me atentando a isso na chamada da função, obrigado pela ajuda!!.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade a lógica do seu código está correcta, o problema está na maneira como chama a função `divicao(1/2)`.

Geralmente os parâmetros em javascritp são separados por *vírgula <kbd>,</kbd>*, e neste caso séria: `divicao(1,2)`.

Nota que se imprimeses os parâmetros terias o seguinte resultado: `valor1=0.5` e o `valor2=undefined`.

Comment: Pessoal obrigado, acabei não me atentando a isso na chamada da função, obrigado pela ajuda!!.